# Replacement part for MAX407 op amp

Tags: components, replacement

Electronics noob here. I need to find a replacement part for a MAX407.

I am assembling this circuit and the shop I'm buying from doesn't have the MAX407 op amp in stock. Since I don't understand all that much about electronics I am looking for a part that I can use in it's place with as few adjustments as possible.

The [circuit](https://arxiv.org/pdf/physics/0701280.pdf) & the MAX407 [specs](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX406-MAX419.pdf).

Can anyone help me understand the key requirements I need to understand for a replacement part?

Thanks

Comment: This is likely to be closed as off topic as we don't answer shopping questions. Also, this is something you can easily do yourself. Almost all online electronics retailers have a parametric search function. Digikey for example has hundreds of those op amps in stock, and if they didn't, you can use the parametric search to look for other products that fit your specifications. You will find a replacement part a lot quicker by looking yourself than asking the internet

Comment: My answer goes into the necessary *specifications* as the OP clearly states little knowledge of electronics.

Comment: If you edit the question to ask about *what are the key specifications I need to consider for a replacement part in this application* the question might well avoid closure.

Comment: @PeterSmith good suggestion. I agree that if you can edit your question the tell us what specifications it is you are looking for, or maybe clarification on what some of them mean, then you may get this question back on topic

Answer (score 3):

Rather than suggesting a part, I will look at the key specifications in the application.

The key requirements appear to be ultra high input impedance, unity gain stable and total supply voltage greater than 9V. The MAX407 has an input bias current (typical) of < 100fA and is unity gain stable. It also has a low gain bandwidth product (8kHz typical) which *may* be important for stability.

A number of parts would do the job:

This [parametric table](https://www.analog.com/en/products/amplifiers/operational-amplifiers/low-input-bias-current-op-amps.html) lists a number of parts from Analog Devices.

Make sure the device can withstand a power source of 9V (many newer parts cannot).

TI has a [rather interesting part](https://www.ti.com/product/LMC6001) (25fA Ib)

I am sure there are many other parts that would do the job.

Gain bandwidth product *may* be important in the sense of keeping it low; you will find those in the ultra low power selection tables (that all the manufacturers have now); these devices (designed for IoT and remote sensors in  many cases) also often have very low input bias current.

Select a part with input bias current < 10pA (max), unity gain stable and Vs (max) > 9V.

Comment: Another important factor is that the selection should include parts with raii to rail output. Not all parts sport that feature and that could be important to the OPs circuit.

Comment: @MichaelKaras - possibly. The application doesn't seem to be the sort of thing that will generate particularly large outputs, though.

Comment: If the OpAmp is socketed as shown (in spite of the text referring to "air wired"), there is no point in specifying fA bias currents.  Guard rings are required to isolate the input pins, particularly from the supply on pin 4. (The LM108 datasheet showed this principle in the early 70's)